# Using a javascript class to create a global state in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

My task is to create a global state in react. I was instructed to use a Javascript class for this purpose. Is it possible? Can Javascript classes be used to create a global state in REACT? I am still a junior developer and I have no experience with this.

We are using an old version of REACT and we use CLASS components.

This is the pattern that I came across, but I have no idea if this can be useful.

```
class State {
  state;
  constructor() {
    this.state = {};
  }

  setState(newState) {
    this.state = { ...this.state, ...newState };
  }

  getState() {
    return this.state;
  }
}
```

Comment: `window.state = new State()`   state is now global.  But really globals are not a good idea, use modules and then you can do -> `export state = new State()`, and then `import {state} from "./my-state"` etc.

Comment: @Keithe Certainly, I did not expect it to work without exporting and importing. 

Do you have an example for exporting and importing state in modules?

Comment: It's basically the above, I'll make an answer so its more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, global state is something you want to avoid.

Javascript these days has something called modules, this makes the need for global state generally redundant.

So using your example ->

`state.js`

```
class State {
  state;
  ......
}

export const state = new State()
```

`consumer.js`

```
import {state} from "./state";

state.setState({});
```

Note: using modules from HTML requires you to load your initial JS file using type module.

eg.

```
<script type="module" src="./consumer.js"/>
```

Finally, if `global` state is absolutely necessary, using the `window` global is a common place to put them.

```
class State {...}

window.myState = new State();
```

And then..

```
window.myState.setState({});
```

If your code is meant to work in Node as well as the Web, you can also use `globalThis`..

```
globalThis.myState = new State();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Obviously, I do not understand the difference between modules and global state. Nor do I understand global state very well.